# Node.js project doesn't run

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am noob in Node.js, and I was assined to a Node.js project, however when I try to put it running with the command `node app.js` the following error appears:

[image]

I don't understand what is happening, I run the command `npm install` to install all the needed dependencies, but the same error is still happening.

This is the project structure:

[image]

And the index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//routes
app.use(require("./routes/index"));
app.use(express.static("public"));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server is up on port " + port);
});
```

Someone have some idea to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code that displays the error so we can see what is the problem

Comment: Which code specifically? It is a big project, so there are a lot of files

Comment: The code that causes the error in question, boiled down to a [mre].

Comment: Make sure there is a file called `app.js` in the directory where you run `node app.js`. The error said there isn't such file.

Comment: This most similar file is index.js, I will edit the question to add the project structure and index.js code

Comment: Then run `node index.js` not `node app.js`

Comment: You rigth, that was the problem, I search in Google how to run a Node.js project, but the command node app.js is for execute the file app.js, and in this project that file doesn't exits. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project structure run:

```
node index.js
```

Look that you try run "node app.js"